# How to share instance of "data" package with "ui" package in Java

Tags: java, package

I've been learning Java for a little while now, and I keep hitting a stumbling block about how to access variable instances across classes.  And try as I might, I have yet to find the answer to this; so many examples I come across when I try to search are single-class, bare-minimum ones, or just completely unreleated (I presume I'm not phrasing my searches properly)

From what I understand, it's best practice to keep data classes separate from UI classes, and to this end, I've taken an old and simple single package app of mine (done in Swing) and am trying to update it to separate packages and JavaFX.

I've managed most of it; had it converted to JavaFX and it was working. I've then split out the app logic into packages and classes, and have hit the same stumbling block.  I launch the app with Main class, then build the UI in the ui package classes.  The "data" package is a maze generator, which the UI will display.

I want to create a maze instance that a Canvas can access in order to draw it, but the menus can access as well to tell it to generate a new maze (or later, take parameters to alter maze generation).

How do I access this maze instance?  From Main?  From my main UI class?  Do I pass a reference to the class that contains the instance into the constructor of the "child" classes then, so I can access the getter there?  Or is this what the C in MVC is, and I need another package?  If so, how do I access across my UI classes?

If it helps, the code I'm working with is here: https://github.com/JakeMoe/jMazeV2

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// UI layer/package:

class UI {
  Controller controller;

  void onCreateMazeButtonPressed() {
    AlgorithmEnum algorithm = currentlySelectedAlgorithm();
    int w = ...; // selected width of graph
    int h = ...; // selected height of graph
    controller.createMaze(algorithm, w, h);
  }

  AlgorithmEnum currentlySelectedAlgorithm() {
    // e.g. translate selection of a combo box to enum value from model layer
  }

  public void update(Graph graph) {
    // draw changed graph
  }
}

// Controller layer/package:

class Controller {
  Model model;
  UI ui; // might be abstracted using a UI interface

  void createMaze(AlgorithmEnum algorithm, int w, int h) {
    Graph graph = model.createGraph(w, h);
    MazeGenerator generator = model.createMazeGenerator(algorithm);
    generator.apply(graph);
    ui.update(graph);
  }
}


// Model layer/package:

class Model {

  Graph createGraph(int w, int h) {
    // return grid graph of given size
  }

  MazeGenerator createMazeGenerator(AlgorithmEnum algorithm) {
    // returns maze generator instance for given algorithm
  }

}
```

That's roughly what I did in my maze demo app at https://github.com/armin-reichert/mazes-demos/tree/master/SwingMazeDemo

However thing get more complicated of you want to visualize the maze creation process and not just the result. To do that I defined listeners for graph changes and handled the model changes in the UI.

Comment: Heh, this question is 8 months old now; I wound up creating the objects in my main class and then passing them into constructors and methods to tie them together.  I think it's similar to what you're doing here, but directly in the UI class, rather than a separate controller class?